# How to configure empty targetNamespace in the Web Service?

Tags: web-services, java-8, cxf, jax-ws, javax

I'm trying to set up empty target namespace when creating the Web Service. Here is the example. My service looks like this:

```
package com.example;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class SampleService
{
    @WebMethod
    public void sampleMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Defined like that, it accepts requests that look like this (please note the *exam* namespace declaration):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:exam="http://example.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <exam:sampleMethod/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to configure the web service to accept the requests that look like this (without the namespace):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sampleMethod/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to set up the targetNamespace to the empty string, but that didn't work - it just defaulted to the *exam* namespace.

`@WebService(targetNamespace="")`

I'm using Apache CXF (3.1.0) to expose the service:

```
<bean id="sampleService" class="com.example.SampleService" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="sampleServiceWs" implementor="#sampleService"
    address="/SampleService" publish="true">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question - I didn't find a way to set the empty targetNamespace, but I managed to leave out the request validation on my service, so that it now accepts the request with the namespace also. To do that, I used the `@EndpointProperty` annotation on top of the service class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.apache.cxf.annotations.EndpointProperty;

@WebService
@EndpointProperty(key = "soap.no.validate.parts", value = "true")
public class SampleService
{
    @WebMethod
    public void sampleMethod()
    {

    }
}
```